# javascript fetch function getting syntax error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i want to fetch json data from openweathermap.org.but whenever i open my console it gives error(syntax error:JSON.parse() like this).and i am unable to find what's wrong with my code.plzz help thanks in advance.

```
<script>
  console.log('about to fetch a rainbow');

  async function catchRainbow() {
    const response = await fetch('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/hourly?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=e4386e3969c8d595d7f2f189cf2f786a');

    const json= await response.json();

   return json;
  }


    catchRainbow()
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error!');
      console.error(error);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: please post the complete error. My guess the api is not delivering json

Comment: also response.json() can be returned without await

Comment: add https in URL api.openweathermap

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the link prefix `http://`/`https://` otherwise JS thinks you mean a local file.

```js
console.log('about to fetch a rainbow');

async function catchRainbow() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/hourly?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=e4386e3969c8d595d7f2f189cf2f786a');

  const json = await response.json();

  return json;
}


catchRainbow()
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error!');
    console.error(error);
  });
```